# Error when executing UnregisterReceiver() in AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, android-widget, android-appwidget

In my app, i'm registering a broadcast receiver that listens to connectivity change if there is no network connection when the widget updates, and I want to unregister it, if there is an internet connection when it updates. The issue i'm struggling with is getting the same instance of the receiver to unregister it, since when the app updates, a new instance of the appwidgetprovide is built, so I don't have a reference to the instance. I tried storing it in SharedPreferences, but that gives me an error: Receiver not registered.

```
    public void decideBroadcastState(Context context){
    // get the network receiver from shared preferences
    preferencesReceiver = Preferences.getSavedObjectFromPreference(context, Constants.SHARED_BROADCAST, this.getBroadcastKey(), NetworkReceiver.class);
    // If there is an internet connection, turn off the broadcast
    if(isInternetConnection){
        // stop listening for a connectivity change
        // If a broadcast was registered, cancel it.
        if(preferencesReceiver != null){
            context.unregisterReceiver(preferencesReceiver);
            Preferences.deleteCurrencyPref(context, Constants.SHARED_BROADCAST, this.getBroadcastKey());
        }

    }// If there's no internet connection, create a new broadcast
    else{
        // Create an intent that will look for a network connection, and will update the
        // widgets, once there is one.

        // if it doesn't exist, create one.
        if(preferencesReceiver == null){
            final String connectivityChange = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(connectivityChange);
            // register it
            // mReceiver is a new instance of the broadcast
            context.getApplicationContext()
                    .registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
            // Store it in preferences
            Preferences.saveCurrencyPref(context, Constants.SHARED_BROADCAST, this.getBroadcastKey(), mReceiver);
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my Preferences class:

```
public class Preferences {

// Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
public static void saveCurrencyPref(Context context, String filePlace, String preferenceKey, Object anObject) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(filePlace, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(anObject);
    editor.putString(preferenceKey, json);
    editor.apply();

}

// Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
public static <NetworkReceiver> NetworkReceiver  getSavedObjectFromPreference(Context context, String filePlace, String preferenceKey, Class<NetworkReceiver> classType) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(filePlace, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.contains(preferenceKey)) {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceKey, "");
        NetworkReceiver obj = gson.fromJson(json, classType);
        return obj;
    }
    return null;
}



static void deleteCurrencyPref(Context context, String filePlace, String preferenceKey) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(filePlace, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.remove(preferenceKey);
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When using `GSON` to store and retrieve an object in the `SharedPreferences` you're serializing and deserializing the object. Doing this will not give you the same instance of the object but a copy of the object with the same values. If you want to know more about how this works search for serialization and the Java heap.

You should be able to store the `BroadcastReceiver` on a static field in your `appWidgetProvider`. I don't know what you're doing exactly but you shouldn't need more than 1 instance of the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all *AppWidgetProvider* is a BroadcastReceiver on steroids, so his lifecycle is same as for BroadcastReceiver. BroadcastReceiver mostly lives 15 seconds (if you don't use goAsync()), making his job on main thread, and die after that (so your process die as well). So register a dynamic BroadcastReceiver in *AppWidgetProvider* not the best idea for that, so Android offer you to use Service (Foreground Service with notification for Android O) to register your dynamic receivers and listen some kind of events.